# How to add a CSS class to fields in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I want to add a CSS class to the HTML output of each field in my field collection.

Please recommend me some module or method to achieve this. I have tried the [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) and [Field Formatter Class](http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) modules but they did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use hook_preprocess_field() in which you can define additional classes for your fields.

Check these to get some idea:
http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal
https://gist.github.com/1184302

Comment: @indrock  what about semantic fields. I read about it but failing to use properly..can u help?

Comment: what about semantic fields. I read about it but failing to use properly..can u help?

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Field Formatter Class](http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) module.

> This module allows site administrators to add classes to the outer HTML wrapper for any field display.
>
> Classes can be specified at the Manage display settings for content types, users and other entities.

**OR**

The [Field Formatter CSS Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) module.

> The Field formatter CSS class module allows you to set any text/list/option field to render as CSS class on the node. This enables the node author to select predefined CSS styling per node.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I have already tried it ..it allows adding class but that class is not visible. As i want to use that class in my jquery , I need to check the position of class.

Comment: I'm not sure, what do you mean by _class is not visible_. If the module allows the addition of classes, you should be able to access it in your jQuery code by something like `$('.classname').function(...`. Or, you can see the edit for Field formatter class module.

Comment: yes i can see the edit for Field formatter class module bt after adding class when i move to add content i am not able to get the class in inspect element.

Comment: These modules will only work if your fields are themed following Drupal standard practice. If they are not working, that suggests that something else is interfering with how fields are rendered. This might be your theme or another module.

Answer (score 2):

By following way, you can add class to a form field:

```
$form['crust_size'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Crust Size'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#description' => 'Select the desired pizza crust size.',
  '#options' => array(t('10"'), t('12"'), t('16"')),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-class')),

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module, this will allow full ability to control the classes and markup on fields in your view modes.  It also allows for better flexibility for layouts

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could achieve this via [Display suite module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) after installing the module. Here is good [tutorial](http://realize.be/configuring-fields-display-suite-drupal-7) for it.

1. Go to manage display of your content type below the manage display form there is a layout option provided by display suite.
2. Select the layout wish and save it.
3. Now you could see a small settings in right side of each field as show in the below screenshot.
4. In choose field template select expert if you want to alter class and html tag wrapped around the field
5. If you just want to add class to fields here is a [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1795368) for it

[image: Snapshot of manage display]