# How to add a class to the <a> link elements within a Multiple Values field in a View?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a Views field (in this case, taxonomy term references) with Multiple Values set to "Display all values in the same row", using the Link formatter and a seperator. I want to add a class to *each* "multiple values" `<a>` element *within* this one field. My output currently looks like this:

```
<div class="field-content">
  <a href="/some/path" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Some name</a>
  , 
  <a href="/another/path" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Another name</a>
</div>
```

I simply want to add classes to the multiple links within the field (and not the the wrapper), like this:

```
<div class="field-content">
  <a class="some-class" href="/some/path" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Some name</a>
  , 
  <a class="some-class" href="/another/path" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Another name</a>
</div>
```

While my fields are taxonomy term references ideally I'd like to know how to do this with any of the many fields that use the "Link" formatter.

Note that this field is included with other fields using a replacement pattern in a custom text field, which [unfortunately seems to prevent field tpl.php options from working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198923/views-is-ignoring-my-field-tpl-php-file-when-the-field-is-used-as-a-replacement).

---

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't find a way even after trying all these things:

- Every combination of Views  **Multiple Field Settings** (which contain no means to add a class) and **Style Settings** (which only affect the field *wrapper*, not each of the multiple items)
- Reading about twenty related questions on here, none of which combine all the elements in my question (CSS class, views, multiple value field), I couldn't find anything that actually works, and the only suggestions that sound like they might work were to [use Display Suite](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/135567/2646), which is a great module but way too big an added overhead for something so minor as adding some classes to some links, or [giving up, cheating and adding the class client-side in jQuery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/61167/add-custom-class-to-link-outputted-by-views), or [brute force with Views PHP](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152629/add-class-to-taxonomy-term-in-view). Most answers don't apply to Multiple Values fields (even when the asker specified such). [This suggestion based on `hook_preprocess_field` looks perfect](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72116/add-class-to-term-reference-output), but it doesn't get called from Views.
- Hacking through the objects available in `hook_preprocess_views_view_field()` and `hook_views_view_field__[view_name]__[view_style]__[field_name]()`. The former seems to treat multiple field items as a lump and not allow changes to each, the latter, when trying to do [something like this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171977), just wouldn't change anything at all
- Scouring Views and Drupal Core's `tpl.php` files, and Views' handler for links. No changes here seemed to make any difference.
- Checking the Views issue queue. I found [a feature request and non-committed patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2515582), adding the ability to set a class like this - but it only applies to multiple field items that are set to be a list item, not seperator-separated items.
- I've considered creating a [custom Views field formatter](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7), but that seems like a terrible solution given that I'd simply be duplicating the existing Link formatter then adding a class. I've looked for a way to hook in to an existing formatter but haven't found one.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to fix this? I've spent so much time on such a seemingly small issue and still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the lot with appropriate Replacement Patterns.

In Views:

**Rewrite Results:**

- Rewrite the output of this field : Tick
- Text : Add as appropriate, ie [field_link-title]
- Output this field as a link : Tick
- Link path : Add as appropriate, ie [field_link-url]
- Link class : Add as appropriate

Above assumes your multi-value field is Link.

If any other field you can just Rewrite with output as link, link path and link class.

THERE does not seem to be a way to write the other original attributes back into the link. They can be obtained from a Replacement Pattern, but there is no form input to add them back.

Comment: Sadly no, this was one of the first things I tried. I'm not talking about the field type "Link", I'm talking about other fields (in this case, a term reference) that using the "Link" formatter. The only replacement patterns available for these are the pre-rendered links `field_NAME` and the ID, in this case `field_NAME_tid`, the title and URL can't be accessed individually through replacement patterns